# Can't connect to RabbitMQ with Flask and Nameko

Tags: python, flask, rabbitmq, amqp, nameko

I'm currently learning how to program in Python and, at the same time, how to use Nameko to make microservices and Flask to make a Website. The idea, here, is to make microservices and let them be available through RabbitMQ while my Flask app is using methods from microservices via RPC and RabbitMQ to display a result or something like that. Of course, RabbitMQ is running and I used iptables to let connections pass. For my first tests, both programs are on the same server. But if Nameko is working perfectly, I can't connect to RabbitMQ with Flask. Here are my codes...

For Nameko program :

```
# -*-coding:utf-8 -*

# namekotesting.py

from nameko.rpc import rpc

class firstService:
        name = "First microservice"
        result = "";

        @rpc
        def mymethode(self, test):
                result = test
                return result
```

And it returns :

```
starting services: First microservice
Connected to amqp://guest:**@127.0.0.1:5672//
```

And for Flask now :

```
#! /usr/bin/python
# -*- coding:utf-8 -*-

from flask import Flask, request
from flasgger import Swagger
from nameko.standalone.rpc import ClusterRpcProxy

app = Flask(__name__)
Swagger(app)
CONFIG = {'AMQP-URI': "amqp://guest:guest@<myipserverhere>:5672"}

@app.route('/')

def mymethode():
        with ClusterRpcProxy(CONFIG) as rpc:
                littletest = rpc.mymethode("hello")

def index():
        return littletest

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', debug=True, port=5000)
```

But here is the result on the page, at port 5000 :

```
 * Serving Flask app "flasktest" (lazy loading)
 * Environment: production
   WARNING: Do not use the development server in a production environment.
   Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Debug mode: on
 * Running on http://0.0.0.0:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
 * Restarting with stat
 * Debugger is active!
 * Debugger PIN: 126-185-375
[03/Jun/2018 18:42:00] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 -
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 2309, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 2295, in wsgi_app
    response = self.handle_exception(e)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1741, in handle_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 2292, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1815, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1718, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1813, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1799, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "/home/oyo/flasktest/flasktest.py", line 21, in mymethode
    with ClusterRpcProxy(CONFIG) as rpc:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nameko/standalone/rpc.py", line 223, in __enter__
    return self.start()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nameko/standalone/rpc.py", line 229, in start
    self._reply_listener.setup()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nameko/rpc.py", line 256, in setup
    self.queue_consumer.register_provider(self)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nameko/standalone/rpc.py", line 119, in register_provider
    amqp_uri = provider.container.config[AMQP_URI_CONFIG_KEY]
KeyError: 'AMQP_URI'
```

Could you explain to me what are my mistakes here ? I would like to know how to use methods from Nameko program, to use microservices (later) for sending and receiving values.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

rename your key in config dictionary instead of `AMQP-URI` try this `AMQP_URI`

```
CONFIG = {'AMQP_URI': "amqp://guest:guest@<myipserverhere>:5672"}
```

Comment: Oh well, thank you for this, I didn't see my typo during hours. It was an underscore in fact... Some new errors but it's not the same thing anymore. I'm going to see why I can't call my object now.